# Question on dec 2013 answer to"How to measure the altitude and azimuth of a star?"

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

I am looking at your [response](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/1104) to the above question.  You stated:

> For Northern Hemisphere, a star that is crossing the North local meridian (that is, between the Zenith and the North Horizon) the latitude is 90−alt=dec−lat
>
> For Northern Hemisphere, a star that is crossing the South local meridian (that is, between the Zenith and the South Horizon) the latitude is 90−alt=lat−dec.

I am simply not seeing this when I looked at image for the culimination of X in : http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/~fv/webnotes/chapter4.htm" ???

Comment: Pleasee put a link to the question and answer that you refer to!

Comment: Or even better, write what you wrote here under the question that you refer to.

Comment: Mike G's answer pertained to a star that is at zenith (i.e., directly overhead), not just at culmination.